# How to access session data as java object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, web-frontend

I'm working with javascript for the first time for a uni project, and can't find any resource on how to solve this issue online. I am coding the back end in java
When I handle the login procedure of the website, the client invokes a servlet that consults the database and creates the session, saving the user data in a bean object (which is a class with a bunch of private variables, and with getter and setter methods), and adding it to the session

Servlet code inside the doPost

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("userData", bean);
```

Once this is done, how do I access a specific attribute of the bean object from front-end javascript?

I tried with `sessionStorage.getItem("userData.getFirstName()")` or `sessionStorage.getItem("firstName)` but they obviously don't work

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly access the Session Attribute from Client side!

first: (not the best solution)
you can save username and passwort (-> Passwort MD5 decrypt) -> The MD5 decrypt Passwort must also store in Database.

second:
you must save the JSESSIONID Coockie (over the Servlet in Backend)

```
String sessionId = session.getId();
Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionId);
response.addCookie(userCookie);
```

third:
on every request you must read username and Passwort like this on your servlet in back-end:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String username= session.getAttribute("username");
String passwort= session.getAttribute("passwort");
```

then you must write a Check-Logic like (only a example):

```
boolean logged=false;
if(session == null){
                logged = false;
}else{
                if(session.getAttribute("name")==null || session.getAttribute("passwort")==null){
                    logged = false;
                }else{
                
                if(chklog.checkLoginUser((String)session.getAttribute("name"), (String)session.getAttribute("passwort"), "1")){
                    name = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
                    passwort = (String)session.getAttribute("passwort");
                    logged = true;
                }
                else{
                    logged=false;
                    userlock=true;
                    if(session != null){
                        session.invalidate();
                    }
                }
                }
            }

if(logged){
 //the show is going on here
}
```

Important:
For Login you must check the Passwort:

```
select count(*) as existscol FROM USER where username='x' AND Password=CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'pwinput'), 2)
```

and for every request you must check the Session Attributes username and password:

select count(*) as existscol FROM USER where username='x' AND Passwort='sessinpassword'

i hope this answers your question.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, thank you very much for your time and help <3

Comment: So... the USER table in this example has two columns, `Passwort` and `Password`, one of which is for session keys and one of which is for actual passwords?  That seems confusing.

Comment: You also refer to "MD5 decrypt"; I think you mean "MD5 hashing", which is more akin to *en*cryption than decryption.  However, you should not use MD5 anymore; it's no longer safe.  Use a newer, more secure hash algorithm.